# Mesh getting distorted with animation

Tags: animation, rigging

My character has rings around his ankles that are getting heavily distorted when animating. What would be best way to fix this?
[image]

Comment: The weighting of the vertices to the armature is not correct, you just need to properly weight them.
This tutorial teaches how to do that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fICQmBEt4Y&ab_channel=RoyalSkies

Comment: If you don't want them to deform at all you could completely solid fill the weight paints on a single bone group.

Comment: can you provide blend file?